# What's a Good Javascript Time Picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, input

What's a good time picker for jquery or standalone js? I would like something like google uses in their calendar where it has a drop down of common times in 15min intervals or lets you manually type in a time and it validates it.

Answer (score 75):

A few resources:

- [TimeDatePicker](https://github.com/perifer/timePicker) (jQuery Plugin)
- [jQuery.timepickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/)
- [jQuery.ptTimeSelect](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html)
- [Time Picker](http://www.pit-r.de/timepicker/demo/pickerDemo.htm)
- [Fancy Time Picker](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/FancyTimePicker.htm)
- [NoGray Time Picker](http://www.nogray.com/time_picker.php)

Answer (score 26):

This is the best I've found till the date http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Depending on the application, this is one of my favorites as well.  I did need to change the minute step period from 1 to 15 though, but that was very easy.

Comment: my favourite from the list. it's easy, simple, and what it needs to. I've used the Any+Time™ Datepicker/Timepicker AJAX Calendar Widget before, but I'm going to give this a try instead.

Comment: The website (and javascript example) are no longer available. Is there a sample of it anywhere else?

Comment: Sliders aren't exactly the easiest or quickest way to select a precise time.

Comment: @Mark I am in agree with your opinion, the simplest way can be either a select list or showing a calculator pad so the user can type.

Answer (score 8):

I wasn't happy with any of the suggested time pickers, so I created my own with inspiration from Perifer's and the HTML5 spec:

http://github.com/gregersrygg/jquery.timeInput

You can either use the [new html5 attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.time.html) for time input (step, min, max), or use an options object:

```
<input type="time" name="myTime" class="time-mm-hh" min="9:00" max="18:00" step="1800" />
<input type="time" name="myTime2" class="time-mm-hh" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='myTime']").timeInput(); // use default or html5 attributes
    $("input[name='myTime2']").timeInput({min: "6:00", max: "15:00", step: 900}); // 15 min intervals from 6:00 am to 3:00 pm
</script>
```

Validates input like this:

- Insert ":" if missing
- Not valid time? Replace with blank
- Not a valid time according to step? Round up/down to closest step

The HTML5 spec doesn't allow am/pm or localized time syntax, so it only allowes the format hh:mm. Seconds is allowed according to spec, but I have not implemented it yet.

It's very "alpha", so there might be some bugs. Feel free to send me patches/pull requests. Have manually tested in IE 6&8, FF, Chrome and Opera (Latest stable on Linux for the latter ones).

Comment: Do you have a demo available?

Comment: Sorry, no. I haven't touched that project in 4 years. Feel free to send pull-requests :)

Answer (score 6):

You could read jQuery creator John Resig's post about it here: http://ejohn.org/blog/picking-time/.

Comment: Takes way too much mouse precision for the average user. It's also not immediately obviously how to use that thing (despite him claiming it's "intuitive") -- I can't look at it and know how it will behave when I mouse over those digits.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is interested in another JavaScript TimPicker, I developed and maintain a jQuery plugin that does the job. It works something like EZ Time JS (although I didn't knew about it until 5 minutes ago :D), allowing users to enter time in almost any way they feel comfortable with, and converting the input into a common format.

Checkout the [jQuery TimePicker Options page](http://wvega.github.com/timepicker/#options) to see it in action.

Comment: The demo is broken (or I didn't understand how to use it!).