# Rails date/time picker (hopefully jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Looking for a date and datetime picker that will integrate fairly seamlessly with Rails.  I'm sure some people must be using something similar.  I have tried

- the unobtrusive date picker plugin but it breaks with the latest release of Rails.
- calendar date select plugin uses prototype which I have removed from my app and don't want to add back.
- active calendar plugin - broken with latest Rails and hacked to fix but doesn't fill out the text fields when a model is loaded.

Thanks very much.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-datetime-picker
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468253/whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker

Answer (score 27):

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

This is the best date time picker I've seen. `milesich` is not actively maintained anymore, and has bugs if the input field is blank. Sure there are solutions (in the comments), but if you look at the code, its one ugly hack.

Trent's implementation is much cleaner. Shorter, easy to understand and minimal CSS to add.  I highly recommend his work.

Comment: Wow, this is a nice timepicker. I've got the milesich timepicker in my (still under development) rails app and it is buggy. Was looking for a good alternative and I think this will be that alternative. Could still do with some tweaking but is the best thing I've seen yet.

Comment: I like the UI of this time picker but I had to abandon it because it was loading extremely slowly for me and my coworker in Firefox 8 (Ubuntu, OS X).  It worked fine in Chrome and on another OS X machine, but I spent half a day trying to debug it and couldn't find out why.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a good write up on one option.

http://milesich.com/timepicker/

[image]
<sub>(source: [milesich.com](http://milesich.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/timepicker.png))</sub>

There is another post here on StackOverflow on a similar topic.  You are looking for something more specific to rails than the OP of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-datetime-picker/1250300#1250300), but it still has some good info.

Comment: Thanks yes I have seen this one and it looks like the most promising.  However the author says it's buggy, and I was hoping to find something that can be dropped right in Rails that is backwards compatible with the default time picker (although I will probably end up using this). Thanks.

Comment: broken link, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The [Any+Time(TM) Datepicker/Timepicker AJAX Calendar Widget](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) uses jQuery and should work seamlessly with Rails.  It provides many date/time formatting options and requires only a single line of your own JS code to attach to any text field.  It also aims to minimize the number of mouse clicks necessary to select a date and/or time, and provides WAI-ARIA keyboard accessibility for users without a mouse.  Did I mention Time Zone support and custom Styles/Themes using CSS and/or jQuery UI? :-)

Comment: Can you please paste some sample code on how to use it with Rails? I've looked around online but haven't found a concrete example of using Datepicker with Rails 3.

Comment: I had to update the example, modifying the directory for the CSS file and the directory for the javascript files to work with the Rails 3 defaults: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/anytime.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/anytime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/anytimetz.js"></script>` Now it works :]