# Is there any way to use a DateTimePicker object on an *.aspx website with Visual Web Developer

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer

I'm creating an on the fly, in house website that's going to be used for a couple of days and then canned.

It would help so much if I could just use the Windows Form DateTimePicker object on my website!

I know that if I add a reference to System.Windows.Forms I can use MessageBox.Show and it works, is the same true for the DateTimePicker?

If I added a reference to System.Windows.Forms and then took the DateTimePicker designer code from my Windows form would this work?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried it?  The last question you ask should be easy enough for you to figure out on your own.  Ok snarkiness aside, I'm actually surprised that MessageBox.Show works.  the compiler must jsut convert it to an alert for an asp.net application.  My gut tells me that it won't do the same for the date picker, but you wont' know until you try ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6836/DateTimePicker-Web-Control). There are many [JavaScript date time picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468253/whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker) you can use as well.