# Javascript date and/or time picker

Tags: javascript

There are quite a few freely available datetime pickers in Javascript. However, you can often select either only date, or date+time. Does anybody know of one which *also* lets you pick only time?

Comment: First Google hit for 'javascript time picker' http://cssgallery.info/javascript-time-pickers/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats a Good Javascript Time Picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468253/whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker)

Comment: @GolezTrol But none of _those_ seem to allow you to set date. I want all three options in the same component.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov But none of _those_ seem to allow you to set date. I want all three options in the same component.

Comment: So you want a picker that allows you to set *only* the time, but the date as well? Maybe you should use a date time picker then? Or reconsider your question. Inputting date and inputting time are two different operations. There is no harm in using a different timepicker when you need just the time. Treat them as different controls, just as a checkbox and a textarea are different controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery there is a pretty cool plugin, which is a combination of both

- http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

only time picker:

- http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Javascript only:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/FancyTimePicker.htm
- http://www.pit-r.de/timepicker/demo/pickerDemo.htm

Comment: Definitely the Trent Richardson one. It's great, you can definitely have just the time only; `$('#div-you-want').timepicker({});`. It will only show the time.

Comment: @JoshuaM Thanks, that's what I was missing!