# How to get <input type="time" /> to display full time picker in IE 10, Firefox, Safari, etc

Tags: html, browser, input, cross-browser

I've been struggling with this all day.

I've been using `<input type="time" />` for a long time in one of our company web apps, and only recently did I discover that this has only been showing a dropdown with 5-minute intervals in IE and Firefox.

I assume the same is happening in Safari, based on [this page](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime).

Is there any solution so that this will work across *all* browsers?

As a side note, it seems pretty ridiculous that these extremely popular browsers wouldn't support the new HTML5 input types. Super frustrating.

Anyways, thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use a javascript time picker. It works more reliably then the default one. Have a look at

[Whats a Good Javascript Time Picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468253/whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Date/time input types are still CSS Working Drafts. So if you want to make it work across *all* browsers, you have no choice but to use a **polyfill**.
Like [this one](https://github.com/jonstipe/time-polyfill) for example.

Comment: Good idea, but it looks and works like trash in IE10. These other browsers need to keep up with the times, like damn.