# HTML5 input type="time" doesn't support on IE

Tags: html

I know `type="time"` doesn't support in IE. Is there any way to make input `type="time"` work in IE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get <input type="time" /> to display full time picker in IE 10, Firefox, Safari, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841843/how-to-get-input-type-time-to-display-full-time-picker-in-ie-10-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Javascript library that implements what modern browsers would do automatically--a so-called polyfill. The first Google result for

> polyfill input type=time

is https://dan503.github.io/time-input-polyfill/, which looks like it could fit the bill.