# g.size() is not a function - Jquery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have been trying to use bootstrap datetimepicker and have all the components on my scripts like Moment JS, bootstrap-date-time js, and bootstrap js but I am getting g.size() is not a function error. I am trying to run the following function

```js
$(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  });
```

Comment: If you use jq3.x, `$.fn.size()` method has been removed. If so, downgrade to any older jq version (2.x?).  BUT maybe this has nothing to do with your issue, just it is hard to guess regarding the fact your question doesn't provide enough info

Comment: I edited the question could you please check again.

Comment: Some script in there may have been passed through Google Closure Compiler in advanced optimization mode without specifying all externs.

Comment: @Arnauld So How can I solve my problem. I need to have a date time picker field.

Comment: If you are indeed using Google Closure Compiler, then try to temporarily disable it and see if it fixes the issue. If not, we don't have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: I don't know why you got a down vote - I'm getting this same (g.size() is not a function) error attempting to use the bootstrap datetimepicker (as instructed here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/, but starting with an existing bootstrap project) - I haven't been able to get to the bottom of this and am now going to choose a different date/time picker -- I'll post back here if/when I find a good one.

Comment: To this date I can't get past this. I am using Angular Bootstrap datetime picker hence

Comment: try with jQuery migrate plugin

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My solution was to find a different datetime picker that actually worked

I found this one: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker, it was quite easy to get working:

1. [download the zip from github](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/archive/master.zip)
2. Include the files :

   <link href="./js/datetimepicker-master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="./js/datetimepicker-master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
3. This HTML

   <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" />
4. And this JS

   $.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

I got this up and working in a tiny fraction of the amount of time I'd wasted trying to get the bootstrap datetimepicker to stop giving me the `g.size()` error.

Of course there are many other datetime pickers available:

#### See this post for many more options : [whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468253/whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker)

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find the solution so I shifted to Angulat Bootstrap datetime picker instead of the Jquery.

Answer (score 12):

`.size()` was removed in version 3 of jQuery, use `.length` instead.

In your example, replace `g.size()` for `g.length`.

Comment: Fixed in .47: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47

Comment: Thanks @MushyPeas, you saved me a headache. Didn't even think to check for a newer version.

Answer (score 9):

The g.size error is known by the developers and exists with newer versions of jquery.

If you wish to use that datetimepicker then go back to jquery 2.1.4 or earlier.

The bug is listed here :

```
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1714
```

Comment: This error in my rails app brought me here. I was using `//= require jquery3`, switching to `//= require jquery2' fixed that problem.

Answer (score 9):

Please use latest [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker) to get rid of this issue. I have used below version and the error is gone.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery **v3.3.1** is used.

Comment: My problem was that using Bootstrap 3 I incorrectly assumed you needed the *3.x.x* version of `bootstrap-datetimepicker` this is not correct moving to *4.x.x* version and corresponding CSS fixed my issues

Comment: This solved my issue!! I was using version 4.17.37. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Check your version of jQuery. I was using the latest(3.1.1) some plugins i use were throwing this error.

according to the docs: The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead.

( it was removed in 3.0 )

so a simple rollback to a version before 3.0 did the trick.

edit: whoops, as A. Wolff says in the comments.

edit 2: another thing... if you want to keep your jquery version up to date, you could include the jquery-migrate plugin to your project - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate