# Can't get PHP to execute inside a <textarea> tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using [this procedure](http://people.irisa.fr/Francois.Schwarzentruber/bibtextohtml/) that reads my local reference bibtex file and automatically formats them inside my HTML page. The procedure is fairly straightforward but something somewhere is not working and after a LOT of debugging I cannot figure it out.

After spending quite some time on this, I have zeroed down the problem to this area in my code:

```
...
...
<textarea hidden name="bibtex_input" id="bibtex_input" cols=50 rows=20>
    <?php echo file_get_contents("ref.bib"); ?>
</textarea>

<div id="bibtex_errors"></div>
<div class="bibtex_template">
    <li>
        <a class="url"><span class="title"></span></a><br>
        <span class="author"></span><br>
        <span class="booktitle"></span>
        <span class="if publisher">
            <span class="publisher"></span>.
        </span>
        <span class="if pages">
          p. <span class="pages"></span>.
        </span>
        <span class="if year">
            <span class="year"></span></span>
        <br>
        <a class="bibtexCodeLink">
            [bibtex]
        </a>
        <br><br>
     </li>
</div>

<ol id="bibtex_display">
</ol>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like PHP cannot execute inside the `textarea` tags for some reason. Outside the `textarea` tags PHP echoes the contents of the file just fine and I can see it on the page. In any case when php is used inside the textarea tags, I cannot see the formatted output on my HTML page and instead see this.

[image]

This is what it should look like.

[image]

**What I have tried:**

- PHP is working. phpinfo() shows me the PHP version when PHP is
  invoked anywhere else on the page.
- JS script, jquery and stylesheet mentioned on the page above is
  included in the header.
- Scripts, html, php files, stylesheets all have proper `644` or `755`
  `chmod` on them. So it shouldn't be a permissions issue(?)
- The page itself is saved as `.php` and not 'html'.
- The 'ref.bib' file's contents are proper and have been tested on the website I linked above. It should work.
- Used [this website](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) to validate my HTML. My HTML syntax should be free of errors.
- Console shows me this:

  jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).size is not a function @http://mywebsite.edu/~me/group/bibtextohtml.js:446:9
  l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29373
  a/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677
   undefined

  TypeError: $(...).size is not a function[Learn More]

**Question:**

How can I get it to work like it shows on the website linked above? Is it a problem with PHP inside textarea tags or something else?

Comment: Perhaps it's related to the `hidden` in your textarea declaration. That's not valid HTML so might be causing the textarea not to display.

Comment: Have you checked the browser **developer** tools console for any errors?

Comment: @Nick OK so removing the `hidden` from `textarea` now shows me a textarea with the contents of my `bib` file in the box. But the formatting is still missing and I still see the `. p ..` below it instead of actual formatted output.

Comment: @JaromandaX Console shows me two errors. They are provided above.

Comment: Does the content of the `ref.bib` appear between the `<textarea>` tags if you look a the source code of the generated page in the browser? What is between the `textarea` tags in the generated source?  To me it looks like a styling issue, in the screenshot the `textarea` appears to have a height of `0` which indicates that some css rules are applied.

Comment: You should probably be using a `div` not a `textarea`.  Contents of a `textarea` are treated as text not html

Comment: @Nick A bib file contains _text_ and not html so to me a `textarea` looks like a valid container for that or a `pre` element.

Comment: Jaromanda's comment was on point when he told me to look at the developer console. The issue is now fixed, please see the solution I posted.

Comment: Your console error message is your answer. Your javascript code is failing due to an obsolete function [`.size()` - https://api.jquery.com/size/](https://api.jquery.com/size/). It was removed in 3.0, and you are using 3.3.1. Need to update to `.length()`

Comment: see `JS script, jquery and stylesheet mentioned on the page above is included in the header.` suggests the right version too :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After help from the community here and after some experimentation according to comments made, I was able to look at the developer console in browser and see that the `jquery` was giving errors. In short, I was using the latest version of `jquery` (3.x) and the tool (that I took from the website linked in my question) was using a function that is deprecated. I went on the page, looked at their source, and used their specific version of `jquery`. It works now.

Alternatively, I also tested updating the deprecated `size()` function to `.length` and it now works with the latest `jquery`.

For more info, see this: [g.size() is not a function - Jquery Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617023/g-size-is-not-a-function-jquery-error)

Answer (score -1):

Procedural PHP is as intelligent as an hammer so I'm pretty sure that if there's any content it is displayed despite of it's adherence with HTML. It not even bother about if there is any html within the page unless you don't tell it to.

It could seem trivial but please check the page source generated with right click->View Page Source and check there and not with just the inspector.

`Textarea` allows only plain text and I think that anything else (e.g. html strings) is just discarded by your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has the correct structure. There are closing tags that confused your textarea tags.

```
<textarea ...>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('...'));?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I tried it this way and the problem persists.

Comment: Disable JavaScript for now and you will see that the textarea data is correctly populated.