# Set datetimepicker default value using PHP datetime value

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker, default-value

I have tried to set datetime value from database to bootstrap datetimepicker input field, but I am not getting the exact date value while editing a record. Also I have tried to convert datetimepicker to insert in database using php. For example, I have tried the following:

- input: `30/12/2021 11:06 PM`
- output: `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Code tried:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['lot_datetime'])); 

$(function () {
  $('#datetimepickerDemo').datetimepicker({
    date: '<?php date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', strtotime($lottery['lotdatetime'])); ?>'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the date property with a `Y-m-d H:i:s` formatted string from php definitely will work.  You should check that you have successfully loaded all required libraries and also check for client-side errors.  There could be any number of things holding you back.  Are you using [JQuery3+ which no longer uses `size`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722548/2943403)? Is the datetimepicker not instantiated and [are you happy to add the moment library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759673/2943403)?

Most importantly, while testing, make sure that *some* kind of datetime expression is actually being printed client-side (from the server-side code).  In your second attempt, you are missing `echo`.

Printing your php data into the javascript block should look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    date: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($lottery['lotdatetime'])); ?>'
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    date: '2021-12-30 23:06:00'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the datetime using this code:

```
$('#datetimepickerDemo').datetimepicker({
    format:"d-M-yy h:mm tt")
});
$('#datetimepickerDemo').val('<?php date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', strtotime($lottery['lotdatetime'])); ?>');
```

Set the datetimepicker date format and set the date value directly to the text field.

Comment: Strange to see this answer upvoted.  Can you spot why the date won't be printed into the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    date: '2021-12-30 23:06:00'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.