# How to change the clickable area of the <input type="time" /> from the icon to the shown time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I wonder, how I could hide the clock icon from the `<input type="time" />` but still be able to click on the shown time to change the current time?

Like in this developer.mozilla example: [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

There is this picture:

[image]

the clock is shown. And when I click on it, I can choose a time, like here:

[image]

What I would like to achieve, is to hide the clock icon and be able to choose a time when I click on the `-- : --` on the left from the icon.

To hide the icon, I can simply write

```
input[type='time']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: none;
    display: none;
}
```

But then it is not clickable.
Of course, if I comment out the `display: none` I can still choose the desired time, but I achieve it by clicking on the empty space right to the `-- : --`.

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.

Just added:

```
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
left:35%;
```

to the `input[type='time']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`

so it is now

```
input[type='time']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    left:35%;
}
```

Comment: Works well, hacky solution, you can try to use Javascript time picker next time. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468253/whats-a-good-javascript-time-picker) out for future reference if it may help.

Comment: Yes, it is hacky, but this is what I got. Maybe you are right to choose a date picker as a solution.